# MacBook Pro 15" displayport/DVI problem

Tags: bootcamp, displayport, dvi

I'm having issues with the video out. When I tried to connect the MacBook to the projector (Christie) via DVI it splashed the macOS desktop for 1 second then a message appeared saying "encrypted" (the projector shows this message not the macbook).

When I use displayport/VGA it works fine.

I did not play any HDCP content (I'm not sure this is even HDCP related).

Anyone with any idea of whats going on? It works fine with Bootcamp Win10.

Below is the link for the DVI input card of the Christie, it is HDCP compliant. 
https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1162034-REG/christie_108_312101_02_dual_link_dvi_input.html

edit: MACOS 10.14, the displayport/DVI adapter is 25 pin which is a digital duallink cable. MacBook Pro 15 Retina mid-2012. Projector is a Christie RPMWU-LED01.

Comment: I tried finding a manual for the input card you referenced, but it's not availalbe.  You probably have to contact [Christie tech support](https://www.christiedigital.com/en-us/about-christie/contact-us) and ask them out Mac compatibility.

Comment: I think there are a view forms of DVI cables.  Maybe the cable is the problem.

Comment: It works for one second where the desktop was shown then blank.